# How do I make a PHP based UDP log viewer?

Tags: php, udp

Ok, so many of you may have heard of games like Garry's Mod or Team Fortress 2. They use a remote RCON logging extension, one I wish to utilize on my website for viewing a live console (and also submitting RCON commands but thats easily done)

Anyway, I have tried searching around to find out the commands I need, but the closest I've found is socket_bind. I tried using this, but the IP of '67.202.70.156' cannot be bound. Here is the error it gives me...

```
Warning: socket_bind() [function.socket-bind]: unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /home1/rainbowd/public_html/udp.php on line 5
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but here is my code. I *borrowed* some code from another stackoverflow question...

```
<?php
$sourceip = '67.202.70.156';
$port = 27500;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($sock, $sourceip, 27500) or die('Could not bind to address');

//this is where the reading loop should go.
while(1)
{
    echo socket_read($sock,1024);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Before you comment on how im defining $port but not using $port, thats because I was using $port and then stopped to test something.

Comment: Bind is used for listening for connections, not for making connections. You can only bind to an address that exists on your server. Perhaps you want `socket_connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use socket_connect() and then socket_select() to do it the way you've outlined it so far in your code above.  Or you might want to use [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) instead; it might be an easier model to use if it fits the desired use.